# Use a macro for sorting VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am importing some data from a txt file to excel

How it looks like :

```
licence: MD2
approval: granted
id: 42FB1010C6B1ED82-0a292138.1
client: CH-W-7000361
username:asd

licence: CAI
approval: granted
id: 42FB1010C6B1ED82-0a292138.1
client: CH-W-7000361
username:qwe
```

So it goes one with multiple entries of the same licence but with different approval's etc

What I want to do is: To filter the data and give it a structure so it should look like:

**Guidance on the 'rule' as to how I want to order the source data. Only once a licence should appear**

- licence
- approval (granted / not granted)
- id / client / username

How it should look like:

```
licence: EDR
approval: granted
  client: pf-W-12365
approval: not granted
  client: QT-B-7000361
  client: C-S-7000361
```

I have done this with a Pivot Table but I would like to automate it with a macro

My code
I have done this

```
Sub Order()
Dim dicKey As String
Dim dicValues As String
Dim dic
Dim data

data = Range("A1:D100") 'load data into variable
    With CreatObject("scripting.dictionary")
        For i = 1 To UBound(data)
            If .Exists(data(i, 1)) Then 'test to see if the key exists
            Else
                dicKey = data(i, 1) 'set the Key
                dicValues = data(i, 2) 'set the value for data to be stored
                .Add dicKey, dicValues
            End If

            Next i
            For Each dic In .Keys
                If .Items(dic) <> "" Then
                Debug.Print (dic)
                'do stuff
                End If
            Next dic
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not very clear to me how you want to end up with the output. What have you done between your input and output examples?

Comment: @DavidG as you see in my first snipped that is the "raw" imported that and in my second snipped its filtered / sorted   according to the rule set I want to order it that my licence is the "key"

Comment: @Niko.K are you getting an error ? if so which line? or the code doesn't give you the output you wanted ?

Comment: @ShaiRado Not a error per se I just dont know how to continue the error is I dont have a clue ..

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative I would recommend you to load your file using **Power Query**. It's a free Add In from Microsoft which is shipped natively with Excel 2013 and 2016 and can be downloaded for free for Excel 2010.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605

The tool allows you to easily set up an automatic query to clean and shape your data. You can split the text values, sort, filter, etc.

It is much more user friendly and produces more maintainable results.

Comment: thank you ever much for your answer, but I would still love a simple button to press since the user does probably not now how to use that correctly

Comment: If the user really only needs to press a button you could still trigger the refresh with one: http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/10/22/refresh-power-query-with-vba/ . However, if the user needs to adjust something in the query, then you're right: Power Query won't be a viable option.